# JQM's Page Events are running twice

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm running this block in a "pageshow", but it runs twice.  I am not sure why this is happening.  However, it does pull the information from the json URL that I cannot provide, but it does not display on the HTML!  Any advice is welcome.  I'm running JQM Beta 1.0rc1.

```
<ul id="test">
    <li>test</li>
</ul>



 $.ajax ({
        async: true,
        url: "http://json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var map_stop = "";
            for (info in data) {
                 var locationid = info.Location_Name;   
            }
            map_stop += '<li>test' + locationid + '</li>';

            $("#test").html(map_stop);

        },
        error: function() {
             alert('error');   
        }
    });
```

**Update:**
Here is something from JSFiddle that kind of shows my problem or is my problem...I'm not sure.
http://jsfiddle.net/uJmkR/2/

**Update again**

I forgot add the data-role divs.
http://jsfiddle.net/uJmkR/4

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON data and JS coding are correct, it's jQuery problem not really concern to jQueryMobile.

Comment: My problem is really JQueryMobile or my method of using Jquery.  Here's an example from JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/uJmkR/2/

Note: I updated.

Comment: I've copied your coding and tested it already. Nothing is wrong. Check the following link and viewsource it. http://www.ppshein.net/examples/jQueryMobile/test/index.html

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the <li>test</li> is not showing up.  Perhaps, I might be just thinking something wrong, but if I remove the page show it works just fine.  I updated it again a bit.  

http://jsfiddle.net/uJmkR/4

Comment: I'm not sure what that link points out other than it doesn't work as it should.